# getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu); error unreachable statement

Tags: android, android-inflate

I am new to Android programming and I need some help for an error `getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu)` which says unreachable statement. please help me with this error.

Comment: please add you code. and may you have written statement after `return` statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If You have added `inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);` below return `super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);` then it will give that error

Your Menu Code Should look like this

```
@Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you. It helped me a lot.